# Are custom posts delete by unregistering post type

Tags: plugin-development

After running `unregister_post_type()` will all of the custom posts be deleted? If not then what `post_type` will be for those? Will they appear in regular post loop? Can they be queried by custom query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By running `unregister_post_type()` custom posts are not deleted from database even they can be retrieved by custom query. They mustn't be appear in regular post loop since their `post_type` remain what was.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried any of the things you mentioned? doesn't seem like that big of a hassle to test it?

First create a new custom post type, create a few posts for it. Than delete the custom post type.

Go to the DB (phpmyadmin) and see if they are still there, check what post type they are.

Now you can try running a query on that custom post type (after its deleted). Did it return the posts or could it not find anything?

You can do all those test yourself in a few minutes.

If in any moment you encounter a problem or something unexpected happened, please share with us the code/result of what you have tried to do